# How to interact with a Smart Phone emulator using Appium?

Tags: java, android, maven, selenium, appium-ios

I'm using the following code to try and swipe left on a iPhone screen (and Android but focused on iOS right now), an App in particular, but I'm unable to get the phone to swipe left.

The intention of the code:

The code below is supposed to swipe the screen left while the app is open and to take a screenshot after every swipe.

What actually happens:

The screen is not interacted with at all and stays stuck the entire time.

If anyone here can conclude that the code below works on their, then I will probably have to try a different .ipa file.

I got the code below from the following [GIST](https://gist.github.com/amit-punjabi/38032dffebb1ce7bad25ebd6db113095#file-swipeios-java)

What I tried:

1. I tried changing the phone and os

   caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone 8 Plus");
   caps.setCapability("os_version", "11");

No luck.

2. I also tried to change the X and Y coordinates to see if that could resolve the issue but no matter the X and Y changes, the screen showed no effect.
3. My suspicion is that I'm not using the proper imports. With the code below, the following imports are unused. Most likely because the code from the GIST could possibly be outdated?

   ```
    import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Set;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
   import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
   import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;
   ```

For more background on this project you can reference this question I asked which displays all the code I'm currently working with

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777847/apachehttpclientfactory-throwing-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-exception)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Set;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;
import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

    public class BrowserStackIOS {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();


        caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone 6S");
        caps.setCapability("os_version", "12");
        caps.setCapability("project", "My First Project");
        caps.setCapability("build", "My First Build");
        caps.setCapability("name", "");
        caps.setCapability("app", "");


        IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://"+userName+":"+accessKey+"@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);

        driver.getContextHandles();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        take_screenshot(driver);


        // First Swipe
        TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
        action.press(PointOption.point(197,619))
                .waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600))) //you can change wait durations as per your requirement
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(209, 392))
                .release()
                .perform();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        take_screenshot(driver);

        // Second Swipe
        action.press(PointOption.point(197,619))
                .waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600))) //you can change wait durations as per your requirement
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(209, 392))
                .release()
                .perform();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        take_screenshot(driver);

        // Third Swipe
        action.press(PointOption.point(197,619))
                .waitAction(new WaitOptions().withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(600))) //you can change wait durations as per your requirement
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(209, 392))
                .release()
                .perform();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        take_screenshot(driver);

        //Test Ends
        driver.getContextHandles();
        driver.quit();

    }
```

Comment: This is for Ios or andriod?

Comment: for it's for iOS but I will also need to do the same test on Android. @Muzzamil

Comment: What you want exactly. You need to setup driver instance to run on emulator?

Comment: I found a temporary solution to this problem. I'm using an apk file of the app instead and it's running so I left iOS aside for now.  @Muzzamil

I'm currently trying to resolve an issue I'm having with clicking on an element. 
Ref: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814868/appium-is-unable-to-find-button-on-android-device

Comment: Okay, I have solution for this but I can check mentioned issue first.