# Appium is unable to find button on android device

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium-android, browserstack

The following is the html code for the button that I'm trying to click.

```
 <Button rounded style={styles.pickBtn} title="get started" onPress={signIn} testID="completeBoarding">
            <Text style={styles.pickBtnText}>GET STARTED</Text>
          </Button>
```

This is the code that I have tried to use to click on said button.

```
String xPath = "//button[normalize-space()='GET STARTED']";
    AndroidElement searchElement = (AndroidElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.xpath(xPath)));
    searchElement.click();
```

-

```
AndroidElement searchElement = (AndroidElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("get started")));
    searchElement.click();
```

-

```
AndroidElement searchElement = (AndroidElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("GET STARTED")));
    searchElement.click();
```

From the html provided above, what is the correct way to click the button? Neither of the above methods I tried ran successfully. Each failed with an error message saying that the element could not be found.

Comment: This is mobile web app? What is the error ?

Comment: Not a web app. Native App. @Muzzamil

Comment: I meant it is native app or web view because html never comes for native app. Xpath syntax is changed for native app and hybrid app so i want to know this

Comment: Errors are all the same in general, example of one is 
"using accessibility id value get started ⇒ An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters." @Muzzamil

Comment: @Muzzamil the html I posted is from the react.js file. if that makes things clearer..

Comment: I need xml from automationviewer or appium inspector. Probably you have to attach picture of xml tree for locators

Comment: Where can I retrieve the xml file? @Muzzamil

Comment: Here you can check how you can locate element.  https://www.guru99.com/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial.html

Comment: I'm running the application through Browserstack by uploading the apk file and running the code from Intellij. Is there another program I could use to locate an element? @Muzzamil

Comment: You should have Android sdk installed on local system. Uiautomatorvier comes in Android sdk. Another way is, connect your device from system or open emulator with open app and then you can use chrome devices on browser

Comment: Ok I am adding in answer please try that

Comment: Please try below solution and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code to click.

```
String xPath = "//*[@title='get started']";
    AndroidElement searchElement = (AndroidElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(MobileBy.xpath(xPath)));
    searchElement.click();
```

**Tap by using text:**

You can tap using `text` with `UiAutomator2`
Add in desired capability `UiAutomator2` if you are using `appium` as automation engine.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

then use this function

```
public void TapByText(String buttonText) {
        String buttonName="new UiSelector().text(\"MY_TEXT\")".replace("MY_TEXT", buttonText);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<WebElement> el = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(buttonName));
        System.out.println(el.size());
        new TouchAction(driver).press(ElementOption.element(el.get(0))).waitAction().release().perform();

    }
```

Comment: I still receive the error saying that such element could not be found. 
https://prnt.sc/qqezxw
https://prnt.sc/qqf03p

Comment: the title is "get started" but the text on the button Is GET STARTED.
I've tried both, neither work. I'm currently trying to set up uiautomatorviewer but I'm running into an error "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/user_name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/user_name/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead."

Comment: I will add a function to click using text

Comment: I have updated the answer and mentioned how you can use uiAutomator2 as automation Engine.

Comment: Worked! Thank you man. I'm going to try and fix the uiautomatorviewer error and see if I can use that for the rest of the testing. It looks very valuable for future testing.

Comment: @Light  Wow. Enjoy mobile automation. can you upvote too? It will make question up in index with same search and help people in future with same issue.

Comment: You got it! Thank you for your help. You'll probably see another question sometime this week from me haha

Comment: UiAutomator is good option specially for search element with scrolling and Tap

Comment: Yes, I really need to set it up. Had I had it set up then this click issue would've been dealt with a lot sooner.